# Overloading the comparison operator== of derived class to scale for any number of base classes

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, boost-mpl

I'd appreciate pointers on how to overload the comparison operator `operator==` of a derived class, `Derived`, in such a way that it scales for any number of base classes, `Base1 , Base2 , Base3 , ...`, (see code below, full version on [ideone](http://ideone.com/FDYuO6)). I suspect bost MPL for_each or some similar construct could probably be harnessed in order to invoke comparisons on a *list* of base class (types).

```
// Real problem has many more more Base classes
class Derived : public Base1 , public Base2
{
public:
    Derived( unsigned& val1 , unsigned& val2 ) : Base1( val1 ) , Base2( val2 )
    {
    }

    // Can the following sequence of steps be generalized 
    // for an arbitrary number of base classes?
    bool operator==( const Derived& rhs ) const 
    {
        const Base1& rhsBase1 = rhs;
        const Base2& rhsBase2 = rhs;

        const Base1& thisBase1 = *this;
        const Base2& thisBase2 = *this;

        return ( thisBase1 == rhsBase1 ) && ( thisBase2 == rhsBase2 );
    }
};
```

**Edit**

I cannot use C++11 (sorry for the omission).

Comment: Not an answer but isn't it simpler to do `Base1::operator== (rhs)` and `Base2::operator== (rhs)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use something like:

```
template <typename T, typename Base, typename ...Bases>
struct compare_bases {
    bool operator () (const T&lhs, const T& rhs) const {
        return static_cast<const Base&>(lhs) == static_cast<const Base&>(rhs)
               && compare_bases <T, Bases...>()(lhs, rhs);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Base>
struct compare_bases<T, Base> {
    bool operator()(const T&lhs, const T& rhs) const {
        return static_cast<const Base&>(lhs) == static_cast<const Base&>(rhs);
    }
};
```

And then

```
bool Derived::operator==( const Derived& rhs ) const
{
    return compare_bases<Derived, Base1, Base2>()(*this, rhs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use C++11. I have amended my question.

Comment: @Olumide: Actually before C++11 you  would implement this with a type-list doing the same, but more cumbersome

Comment: @DieterLücking TypeLists you mean? Yes I know of them but I'm having difficulty finding anything that resembles a Loki-style TypeList in Boost MPL.

Comment: @Olumide [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e25a15811e0811d6) is a non-c++11 version of this answer that uses Boost.Preprocessor to emulate the variadic templates. (I have also changed the structs for functions). If you want more than 10 bases you'll have to change both `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO` invocations.

Comment: Your answer provided the kernel of the idea of the C++03 implementation, so I'm marking it as the answer.